# Hugo: don't publish future posts

Tags: web-deployment, netlify, hugo

I have a site that I am building with hugo and deploying on Netlify with the standard `hugo` command. I have a post with the following frontmatter:

```
---
weight: 99
title: foobar
date: 2022-5-12T1:00:00-07:00
---
```

Even though `date` is in the future (as of this writing) the post is being built along with the rest of the site and is visible.

According to [this post](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/usage/#draft-future-and-expired-content) it shouldn't be visible because `date` is in the future. I haven't done any [date configuration](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration/#configure-dates) in my `config.toml` file, but just to check, I tried changing `date` to `publishDate`:

```
---
weight: 99
title: foobar
publishDate: 2022-5-12T1:00:00-07:00
---
```

I even tried including both `date` and `publishDate`, but nothing I've tried so far has had the desired effect. The post still shows up even though the date is in the future.

Again, on Netlify the site is being build with the `hugo` command, so the `--buildFuture` option is not included. This is also an issue when I view my site locally with the `hugo server` command. Is there anything else I should check for or something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Turns out the date format is pickier than I thought. `2022-5-12T1:00:00-07:00` wasn't being recognized as a valid date, so it defaulted to January 1, 0001. Once I changed the date to `2022-05-12T1:00:00-07:00` (making the month two digits instead of one) it recognized the correct date and worked as expected.